# Scan through an image for a specific point in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of size 480 (height) by 640 (width). I also have a matrix of size [1 x 280]. These 280 values are points which can be found in the image.

I would like to find out what are the points from the matrix that can be found in a particular section of the image. I did a nested `for` loop to specify the location where I want to scan to search for the points, but I have trouble doing the "scanning".

```
% matrixC = [435 560 424 132 453 ........ 596] for example of size 280
for height = 1:480
    for width = 635:640
    W = C(max);
    end
end
```

This it only displays W as the greatest value of C, but I need to only show the greatest value of C within the sections of between 1 and 480 for the height, and 635 to 640 for the width. How do I write code to only scan the particular section I am interested in, and if there are, like, 10 numbers found within that section, how do I select them?

Comment: Are you looking just for the existence of values in the image area or their max value, if they exist in `C`? This is somehow confusing in your post. Also, what is `W` and `C` in your code? `max()` is  a MATLAB operator, unless you are overriding that, i.e. setting  `max=something` earlier. If so the double-for loop will have no effect, `W` will be equal to the value of `C` at location `max`. Please consider revising and clarifying.

Comment: I am looking for the existence of values of C in that particular section which I am scanning for. C is a [1 x 280] double array. W is just an array that I am creating to store values of C found in the section. The C(max) is probably wrong. Basically that is just my idea of the code, but I'm pretty sure its wrong. I hope you can understand the main idea that I am trying to get, which is to just scan the allocated section within the for loop for values that can be found in the array "C".

Comment: The code in my answer is a solution for that then. The locations of 1 in the section (named `imageMember`) will give you locations of possible values of C. You can then do `W = imagePart(imageMember)` to get those specific values. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: When I do W = imagePart(imageMember), I only get an empty matrix of 1 by 0. I am using Matlab 7.10.0 (R2010a)

Comment: For my image of size 480 by 640, do I replace 'imageC = randi(256,480,640)' with 'imageC = (480,640) then? And for vectorW, do I replace it with 'vectorW = C;' since my array of points are stored in C?

Comment: yes, `imageC` and `vectorW` are just names, and are given random values. Only their size matters for the example, i.e. you have an image (matrix) of size 480 x 640 (or any size) and a vector C of size 1 x 280 (or any length).

Comment: imageC = dim(480,640); % random image
vectorW = C(1,280);  % random vector of points 

imagePart = imageC(1:480, 635:640, 1:3); % select section by  indexing
imageMember = ismember(imagePart, vectorW);  % check membership 
W = imageC(imageMember);                                                                      when I do that, W = empty matrix. Why is that so? Can you tell me where did I go wrong.

Comment: See my updated answer. By `vectorW = C(1,280)` you are assigning in `vectorW` a single point from `C`, namely (1,280). Also, what is `dim()`? You define a 2D matrix from it and then for `imagePart` you  index a 3d image. Please try things out first and figure what is it you input and want to output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and direct indexing in the image matrix to get a binary matrix of "is" or "is-not" values.

```
imageC = randi(256, 480, 640); % random image
vectorW = randi(256, 1, 280);  % random vector of points 

imagePart = imageC(1:480, 635:640); % select section by indexing
imageMember = ismember(imagePart, vectorW);  % check membership
```

**Update** (changing `vectorW` to `C`, adding handling for 3-channel image, and actual point value return): You can apply your own image `imageC` and vector `C` on the following by replacing first two lines.

```
imageC = randi(256, 480, 640, 3); % (random) image [480 x 640 x 3]
C = randi(256, 1, 280);  % (random) vector of points [1 x 280]

imagePart = imageC(1:480, 635:640, :); % select section by indexing [480 x 6 x 3]
imageMember = ismember(imagePart, C);  % check membership [480 x 6 x 3] 
pointsInImage = unique(imagePart(imageMember)); % unique set of points from C found in imagePart
```

Comment: By doing that, after checking what imageMember is, it is an array of [1 1 1 1 1 1]. For vectorW, i declared it as my array "C", namely vectorW = C; How does that enable me to find out which points in the array C are inside the boundaries?

Comment: 1) Size of `imageMember` should be the same as the size of the image area you are checking, in the above `[480 x 6]`, 2) if you get `imageMember == [1 1 1 1 1 1]` this means that you are checking a 6-element part of the image and everything in there is a point from vectorW (which can be of arbitrary length since it is treated as a set or pool of values).